# How to insert echo statements in order to insert RDFa Lite markup

Tags: php, html, echo, rdfa

I have an issue that I can't seem to solve, without breaking the entire page.

I need to edit this following code and insert extra echo statements. The echo statements are needed in order to markup with RDFa Lite.

```php
echo '<td><a href="sportsteam.php?id='.$row['SportsTeam_id'].'">'.$row['name'].'?></a></td>
                                          <td>'.$row['startDate'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row['endDate'].'</td>
                                        </tr>';
```

I need to insert the echo statements before *and* after `$row['name']`, `$row['startDate']` and `$row['endDate']`.

Answer (score 0):

Better add it to a variable and concatenate with '.'

```
$value = '<td><a href="sportsteam.php?id='.$row['SportsTeam_id'].'">'.$row['name'].'?></a></td>' ;
$value .= '<td>'.$row['startDate'].'</td>';
$value .= '<td>'.$row['endDate'].'</td></tr>';
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is activated, always on since PHP 5.4.

```
<?='<tr>'?>
<?='<td><a href="sportsteam.php?id=' . $row['SportsTeam_id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '?></a></td>'?>
<?='<td>' . $row['startDate'] . '</td>'?>
<?='<td>' . $row['endDate'] . '</td>'?>
<?='</tr>'?>
```

Or...

```
<?php
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="sportsteam.php?id=' . $row['SportsTeam_id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '?></a></td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['startDate'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['endDate'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
?>
```